# How to control a memory overflow correctly in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm tryng add into an array all pixels value of a picture. If the picture is so big my app lost connection with assets and crash..

How can I check if memory is growing to stop and show alert, because I don't know what is the max  image size that it can do to prevent this while load a picture.

My code is:

```
 -(NSArray*)getRGBAFromImage:(UIImage*)image atx:(int)xp atY:(int)yp
 {
NSMutableArray *resultColor = [NSMutableArray array];
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);
// Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yp) + xp * bytesPerPixel;

 //EDIT: THIS IS THE LOOP
 for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
{
    CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     *1) ;
    CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] *1) ;
    CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] *1) ;
    CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] *1) ;
    byteIndex += bytesPerPixel;

    redTotal = redTotal+red;
    greenTotal = greenTotal + green;
    blueTotal = blueTotal + blue;

    UIColor *acolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
    [result addObject:acolor];


}    
NSLog(@"width:%i hight:%i Color:%@",width,height,[color description]);
free(rawData);
return resultColor;
 }
```

Or should I add this to a queue??

Thanks!

Comment: How big is the image (height & width) that is causing the crash?

Comment: Are you repeatedly calling `getRGBAFromImage` or calling it in a loop? Where is the crash happening and exactly what is the error message?

Comment: This exactly: "188:4508] Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died" And pop up xcode 'message restore the conection and run app again'.   The image with 3264x2448 crash. I know that is so big, but how can I advert to user with the correctly size?     I call this one time and the loop is the for that is on my function. Thanks!  NOTE: Edit my code, I forget the loop into function..

Answer (score 0):

Wile the image is rather large (32MB) the array will be much larger since it is an array of objects. There will be 8M UIColor color objects. Just the array of pointers to the UIColor objects in a 64-bit device will take 64MB and then add in 8M times the size of a UIColor object.

You need to find another way of handling this.